# Would Samsung Galaxy Note II battery work on Samsung Galaxy Note?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note, samsung-galaxy-note-2

Would Samsung Galaxy Note II battery work on Samsung Galaxy Note?
Would it fit and would the 3100mAh be a problem because the original of the Note is only 2500mAh?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It won't fit, The Note 2 batteries are physically larger than the Note 1's battery slots. Your best bet is finding a good third-party extended battery.